# required rule not working in model for yii2basic

Tags: yii2-basic-app, yii2-model

i have generated a model by gii for my table which by default generated required rule for some database field in rules section. But i don't want some of the fields of them to be required so i simply removed them from required portion. but this is not working.
what i have by default is this

```
[['grp_name', 'sub_grp', 'member_name',  'fathers_name', 'd_o_b', 'occupation', , 'address', 'phone_no', 'nomniee_one',  'per_allotment_one',  'per_allotment_two' ], 'required'],
```

but i don't want to make `'per_allotment_two'` required so iremoved it and made this

```
  [['grp_name', 'sub_grp', 'member_name',  'fathers_name', 'd_o_b', 'occupation', , 'address', 'phone_no', 'nomniee_one',  'per_allotment_one' ], 'required'],
```

but got this error
[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the per_allotment_two is not required means in the database make the
per_allotment_two has default null.Otherwise provide some default value to it.
Then remove the per_allotment_two from the model in the rules section.It will work.